# object and attributes in python h.w

Tags: python

I have h.w to built a simple class.
I have problems with two def: DisOwnerCars and DisAllOwnerCars.

this is my code (after corrections):

```
 class Car:

    def __init__(self, manufacture, production_year):
        self.manufacture = manufacture
        self.production_year = production_year

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.manufacture, self.production_year)

class CarOwner:

    car_owners = []
    all_cars = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cars = []
        CarOwner.car_owners.append(self)

    def add_car (self, car):
        self.cars.append(car)
        CarOwner.all_cars.append(car)


    def DisAllCars():

        for owners in CarOwner.car_owners:
            for car in owners.cars:
                print(car)

    def DisAllCarsSorted():

        print(sorted(CarOwner.all_cars, key=lambda x: x.manufacture))


def DisOwnerCars(car_owner):
    for car in car_owner.cars:
        print(car)

def DisAllOwnerCars():
    for owners in CarOwner.car_owners:
        print('Cars owned by {}:'.format(owners.name))
        for car in owners.cars:
            print(car)        


jane = CarOwner("Jane")
jane.add_car(Car("Mitsubishi", 2017))

bob = CarOwner("Bob")
bob.add_car(Car("Mazda", 2013))
bob.add_car(Car("BMW", 2012))

DisOwnerCars(jane)
DisAllOwnerCars()
DisAllCarsSorted()
DisAllCars()
```

I still gets some errors in the DisAllCarsSorted().

the error:

File "", line 3, in DisAllCarsSorted
    print(sorted(CarOwner.all_cars))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Car' and 'Car'

Comment: @Uriel that is what my teacher asked for, do you know what is the problem in the DisOwnerCars()?

Comment: @hila_de Since this is homework, I'm not going to flat out tell you what is wrong. But I will offer some tips. First, think about what your putting into `CarOwners.owners`. the `owner` variable in your for loop will have the type of whatever is in your list. If you have a hard time visualizing, print out the list, so you can clearly see what's inside. Once you see, the problem should become clear.

Comment: @hila_de take a look on the answer I posted. If this is homework, I can already tell you it's incomplete and you should look fartherwrite the main part which is storing the owners; but it will give you a general sense about classes. Notice the use of list to keep all owners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to get the purpose of classes differently than what it comes to provide.

Classes are prototypes - like reciepe or a blueprint - for creating instance. Therefore, the class `CarOwner` is a reciepe for what properties and actions can a car owner have. You should not use classes as containers to data, like collecting a list of all owners. That is the use case for lists, and possibly metaclasses.

If you want the list of all car owners, you should create several instances of a `CarOwner` and keep them in a list, not save all of the data in a set inside the different instances.

I've modified your code a little bit, to provide an example for what does a simple OOP looks like and how to encapsulate the classes; note the abstraction of the class `Car`, the use of `__str__`, and the initializer, that do nothing *but* initialize; I hope it will serve as a good example.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, manufacture, production_year):
        self.manufacture = manufacture
        self.production_year = production_year

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.manufacture, self.production_year)

class CarOwner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cars = []

    def add_car (self, car):
        self.cars.append(car)

def print_cars (car_owner):
    for car in car_owner.cars:
        print(car)

def print_owners (car_owners):
    for car_owner in car_owners:
        print('Cars owned by {}:'.format(car_owner.name))
        for car in car_owner.cars:
            print(car)


jane = CarOwner("Jane")
jane.add_car(Car("Mitsubishi", 2017))

bob = CarOwner("Bob")
bob.add_car(Car("Mazda", 2013))
bob.add_car(Car("BMW", 2012))

owners = [jane, bob]

print_cars(jane)
print('===')
print_owners(owners)
```

Comment: why do I need the  __str__?

Comment: @hila_de invocation for implicit `str` (called when calling `print`). you probably should not use it if your class level is high-school.

Comment: @Uriel I'm just curious as to why you think `__str__()` should not be used at the high-school level of programming?

Comment: @ChristianDean I think it shouldn't be used, not learned; just because many teacher (among them many I've seen) would treat it as a cheat (unlearned material and stuff) and sometimes even wouldn't understand it themselves

Comment: @Uriel I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: if I do it like you suggested I don't know how to display all the cars (not for specific owner).

Comment: @hila_de that would be the `print_cars` function. under what class level are you asked to do this task?

Comment: first degree and in print_cars  I give him specific owner, but I need to display a sorted list of all cars..

Comment: also, sorting is made in context of one object bigger than another. what comparison are you doing? lexicographic? year of production?

Comment: @Uriel that what I had before:      def DisAllCarsSorted(): print(sorted(CarOwner.cars)). now I don't know how to go over every car without giving a specifc owner..

Comment: @hila_de then sort with key: `sorted(car_owner.cars, key=lambda x: x.manufacture)`. regarding printing all cars: that would, again, depend on the form you keep the records. if you want a nice format, i would suggest you set a global variable, `car_owners = []`, and inside the `CarOwner`'s `__init__` add `car_owners.append(self)`. then you can set `print_owners` default to the global `car_owners`.

Comment: @Uriel tried this: def DisAllCars():
    
    cars = []
    for owners in CarOwner.car_owners:
            cars.append(owners.cars)
    print(cars) and it didn't worked

Comment: @hila_de again: you shouldnt save car_owners as a property of the type CarOwner. is one of the properties used to describe a student is his entire set of pals at the class?

Comment: @Uriel that is what I did. I have corrected my code above.